# How to escape `--` in bash script for git log command

Tags: bash, shell-script

The `git log` command can specify a custom format, ie,

```
git log --pretty=format:'%cD %<(20)%cn %f'
```

Will format the log files into columns.

But I can't get this to work in a two line bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
CMD="git log --pretty=format:'%cD %<(20)%cn %f'"
$CMD
```

It looks like bash is adding backslashes in front of '--' and single quotes...

```
+ CMD='git log --pretty=format:'\''%cD %<(20)%cn %f'\'''
+ git log '--pretty=format:'\''%cD' '%<(20)%cn' '%f'\'''
fatal: ambiguous argument '%<(20)%cn': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I've tried escaping different parts of the command but can't git it to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: bash is adding slashes only to output of `set -xv`. Use an array instead of a string to store a command with parameters.

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: It's not the dashes, it's the spaces.

Comment: It is because of spaces, you can use `git log --pretty=format:'%cD%<(20)%cn%f'` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks all.  In the link noted in the close message I found that using `eval` fixed the problem!